# Arrange Words in descending order of their length

Tags: java

Requirement:

> Write a program to accept a string and print the words in descending > order of their length, **without using arrays**.

example:

> Input=I love my country India
>
> Output=country India love my I

I have tried to solve by using nested loop but it will take time for bigger inputs. suggest a better alternative algorithm...

```
//Input=I love my country India
//Output=country India love my I
public static void main(String[] JVJplus)
{
    String s,temp="",newS="";
    int i,j;
    System.out.print("Entet s=");
    s=in.nextLine()+" ";
    for(i=s.length();i>0;i--)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s.length();j++)
        {
            char c=s.charAt(j);
            if(c!=' ')
                temp+=c;
            else
            {
                if(temp.length()==i)
                    newS+=temp+" ";
                temp="";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Output="+newS);
}
```

Comment: `without using arrays` means that no Arrays, ArrayLists, Comparators can be part of the solution? If all these are prohibited then probably your solution is more than enough.

Comment: I agree with elefasGR. And for the record: you are asking how to improve working code. Such requests could/should go to codereview.stackexchange.com ... and keep in mind: the whole point of this "puzzle" is to **not** use arrays. In that sense: you would not solve this problem in that many **anyway**; so you really dont need to worry about the performance of your solution too much. In other words: somehow you have to "compensate" for not being able to use arrays. It is no surprise that a solution that saves on memory requires "more" cpu cycles!

Comment: Playing devil’s advocate, would not a String be technically an “array” of characters? And you use this “array” with: char c=s.charAt(j);

Comment: Question's a bit vague surely?  elefasGR assumes Comparators are excluded... why?  What about a solution using SortedSet?  A set is a collection but not an array, list, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to use Arrays, what about regex?

So the idea is to use a for loop with a temporary int variable `i`, which is initialized with the length of the `input` String and is decreased by 1 every iteration.

In the loop we are checking with a regex if the `input` string contains any word(s) with length = i, that is what the regex `\\b\\w{"+i+"}\\b` matches: exactly `i` consecutive word characters(= any word with length=i)

And finally, if there are matches we print them to sysout.

We start with `i = input.length()` because we want the longest words first and it might be possible that the whole input String is a single word.

```
    String input = "I love my country India";
    for (int i = input.length(); i > 0 ; i--) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{"+i+"}\\b").matcher(input);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.print(m.group(0) +" ");
        }
    }
```

prints `country India love my I`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkedHashMap(If in the case of words having the same length, you want to order them on the basis of insertion order) otherwise you can also use HashMap.

I have used LinkedHashMap for the solution.

```
Input: "I love my country India"
```

Solution:

```
String sentence = "I love my country India";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> hm = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(String word : sentence.split(" ")){

        hm.put(word, word.length()); 

    }

    hm.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .forEach(e->{
    sb.append(e.getKey() + " ");  
    });


String result = sb.substring(0).trim();

System.out.print(result);
```

```
Output: "country India love my I"
```

In this case, using a HashMap will give the same output as there are no words of the same length in the string.